# video streaming and conversion in real time

Tags: video

I want to ask if you know any method/programs to streaming video in time where it is converting from for example avi to ogg format ? Can i use to this a ffmpeg program

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) for this. It has a transcoding wizard that will let you transcode and stream at the same time.